# How can I split out change types from an audit table when they have been rolled up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am attempting to build a query based on an audit table, so that changes to data can be categorised as Insert, Amend or Delete.

Essentially I have a requests tables that stores the old value and new value of two properties for each request:

| RequestID | Value1Old | Value1New | Value2Old | Value2New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 50 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 50 | 100 | NULL | 100 |
| 3 | 100 | 200 | 100 | 300 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | 300 | 500 |
| 5 | 200 | 0 | 600 | 1000 |
| 6 | NULL | NULL | 1000 | 0 |

I am looking generate a report based on this, splitting out the change category of each request along with the old and new values.  As can be seen from the table above, for each request there can be a combination of change category, e.g. insert of Value1 and an amendment of Value2; or an amendment of Value1 and Value2.

For each category of change in a request there would be a separate row, i.e. in the data above requests 2 and 5 have multiple categories of changes and so are split out:

| RequestID | Change | Value1Old | Value1New | Value2Old | Value2New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Insert | NULL | 50 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Insert | NULL | NULL | NULL | 100 |
| 2 | Amend | 50 | 100 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Amend | 100 | 200 | 100 | 300 |
| 4 | Amend | NULL | NULL | 300 | 500 |
| 5 | Amend | NULL | NULL | 600 | 1000 |
| 5 | Delete | 200 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | Delete | NULL | NULL | 1000 | 0 |

I've been able to get the results that I want via a long winded query, but there must be a better way?  It's not very scalable, and ultimately I'm looking to do this on around 15 values.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT
    RequestID,
    UpdateTypes.[Name],
    CASE
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Insert' THEN NULL
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Delete' AND Value1New = 0 THEN Value1Old
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Amend' AND Value1New <> 0 THEN Value1Old
         ELSE NULL
    END Value1Old,
    CASE
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Insert' AND Value1Old IS NULL THEN Value1New
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Delete' AND Value1New = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Amend' AND Value1Old <> 0 AND Value1New <> 0 THEN Value1New
         ELSE NULL
    END Value1New,
    CASE
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Insert' THEN NULL
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Delete' AND Value2New = 0 THEN Value2Old
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Amend' AND Value2Old <> 0 AND Value2New <> 0 THEN Value2Old
         ELSE NULL
    END Value2Old,
    CASE
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Insert' AND Value2Old IS NULL THEN Value2New
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Delete' AND Value2New = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN UpdateTypes.[Name] = 'Amend' AND Value2Old <> 0 AND Value2New <> 0 THEN Value2New
         ELSE NULL
    END Value2New
  FROM
    Requests,
    (SELECT 'Insert' [Name] UNION SELECT 'Amend' UNION SELECT 'Delete') AS UpdateTypes)  Updates
WHERE
    ((Updates.[Name] = 'Insert')
AND  ((Value1Old IS NULL AND Value1New IS NOT NULL)
OR    (Value2Old IS NULL AND Value2New IS NOT NULL)))
OR  ((Updates.[Name] = 'Delete')
AND  ((Value1Old IS NOT NULL AND Value1New = 0)
OR    (Value2Old IS NOT NULL AND Value2New = 0)))
OR  ((Updates.[Name] = 'Amend')
AND  ((Value1Old IS NOT NULL AND Value1New > 0)
OR    (Value2Old IS NOT NULL AND Value2New > 0)))
ORDER BY
  RequestID
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle with the data, my current query and expected results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ed0e/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a possible improvement would be to move the logic to determine the change into a function:

```
create or alter function fnChange (@Old int, @New int) 
returns varchar(10) as
begin
    return (
    select 
        case
            when IsNull(@Old,0)=IsNull(@New,0) then null
        else
            case when @New=0 or @new is null then 'Delete' else
                case when @Old is null then 'Insert'
                else 'Amend' end
            end
        end 
    )
end
```

Then you can re-use it to simplify. The following I believe gives you your desired output:

```
with r as (
    select RequestId, dbo.fnChange(Value1Old,Value1New) Change, Value1Old, Value1New, null Value2Old, null Value2New
    from Requests
    union all
    select RequestId, dbo.fnChange(Value2Old,Value2New) Change, null Value1Old, null Value1New, Value2Old, Value2New
    from Requests
)
select requestId, Change, 
    Max(Value1Old) Value1Old, Max(Value1New) value1New,
    Max(Value2Old) Value2Old, Max(Value2New) value2New
from r where change is not null
group by requestId, Change
order by requestId, change desc
```

See [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c81e413ec4c483dc2ef7c4923e3293f1)